# Restrict android application to specific region through code

Tags: android, geolocation, location, google-play

I've read that we can restrict access to App when publishing on the Android Market to a particular location. We can restrict by country but, what I want is to restrict access based on the state or a city where they live. And, the App access will be expanded to other cities or states in the later updates.

Is there a way we can restrict the users from using the App based on their location. If there is a way could you explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user's current geo-point using "Location Manager" and there by track where the user is located at, then there restrict the user.

Comment: Can you explain little more about how to restrict access to the user once location details are received?

Comment: You need to get the geopoint first, then get the location(City), then if the city is a one that need to restrict, avoid user interaction with the app. Do this at the starting time.